# Trace file name is invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to copy the trace file information to SQL table with `fn_trace_gettable` function, but while running this function I am getting 'Trace file name is invalid'. And I confirmed the path and file name are correct and the default trace is enabled. Following is my SQL code, what I am doing wrong?

```
USE TestDB
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[traceTable]
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(N'‪D:\MAT25.trc', default)
```

Error Message:

> Msg 19050, Level 16, State 6, Line 11
> Trace file name '‪‪D:\MAT25.trc' is invalid.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: did you check the path against `sys.traces` ?

Comment: What is the D drive on your SQL Server machine?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, this is the path -F:\SQL_DATA\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_125.trc

Comment: @DavidG I am using D drive for storing files like .trc, .csv etc. But I got the above issue in F and E drives too

Comment: Yes, but are the D/E/F drives actually local hard drives in the box or mapped to a network share for example?

Comment: @DavidG these are local hard drives

Comment: Just to confirm... the file paths need to be relative to SQL Server's view of file systems, not your local workstation's.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, these paths are relative to SQL server. I already reading some CSV files from that path with sql bulk insert queries